# How to find a equation from approximate curve?

Tags: approximation, algebraic-curves, curves

I want to know a way to find equation from a curve.
[image]

for example, if I have 4 point (1, 3.5), (2, 4.3), (3, 7.2), (4, 8) then how to find a good approximation equation ?

What if I got above curve then how to get a equation like p(x)=9−10.05x+5.25x2−0.7x3 ? Might be above curve have like this p(x) = ...x^10000

Also what is the Best way to approximate a curve as soon as possible?

Comment: Probably a linear regression would suffice.

Comment: You may use [Alpha 1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Fit%20%281%2C%203.5%29%2C%20%282%2C%204.3%29%2C%20%283%2C%207.2%29%2C%20%284%2C%208%29) or [Alpha 2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Cubic%20fit%20%281%2C%203.5%29%2C%20%282%2C%204.3%29%2C%20%283%2C%207.2%29%2C%20%284%2C%208%29) for a quick answer but more points would help...

Comment: This cannot be called a curve, it's just four independent points. This is not enough information to tell what a good approximation would be. You need to tell us more about the underlying model/functional relation that you expect.

Comment: In the first place, do you mean approximation or interpolation ?

Comment: Starting with a physical model would be better but you may try to adjust the constants appearing in these approximations ($30$ is fixed as the upper-bound) : 
\begin{align}
&x\mapsto 200000\;e^{-3(30/x)^{0.7}}(1-(x/30)^{1.8})^{0.8}\\
&x\mapsto 14000\;(x/30)^4\;(1-(x/30)^{1.8})^{0.8}\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

One idea that comes to mind is to use matrices to solve for a polynomial that goes through each of those points. With 4 points, we demand a third degree polynomial of the form 
$$p(x)=a+bx+cx^2+dx^3$$ 
Taking those four points we have the system of equations
$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
    a & b & c & d & 3.5 \\
    a & 2b & 4c & 8d & 4.3 \\
    a & 3b & 9c & 27d & 7.2 \\
    a & 4b & 16c & 64d & 8 \\
  \end{array}\right]
$$
You can use a graphing calculator or any computer algebra software (or do it manually if you're so inclined) to obtain the rref:
$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
    a & 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 \\
    0 & b & 0 & 0 & -10.05 \\
    0 & 0 & c & 0 & 5.25 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & d & -0.7 \\
  \end{array}\right]
$$
Thus we have $$p(x)=9-10.05x+5.25x^2-0.7x^3$$
which fits all the required points. My apologies if this method is not quite as civilized an approach as you were hoping for, curious to see what else is out there.

Comment: This is not an approximation, is it ?

Comment: Sir, thanks for letting me. I think this answer very closer to answer what I want. But this example have 4 point, it seems that easy to make equation. But what if I have got 10000 point over then the equation have 10000 degree(....x^10000). Is this manner correct to make equation or another way exist?

Comment: No at that point, I don't think it's feasible to try to make sure your "approximation" goes through every single point; there are more sophisticated methods. Even with only 4 points, you could use a linear regression technique to a line that accurately estimates those points there (if you think the trend is likely to be linear). You could use excel or the like to do this, but information is out there if you're trying to ask about how regression actually works.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to have some idea of what the function will look like:
\begin{align}
y &= a \ln x + b \\ 
y &= ax + b \\
y &= ae^x + b \\  
y &= \sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i \\
y &= \dfrac{\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i}{\sum_{j=0}^m a_ix^i} \\
y &= \operatorname{spline}(x; \alpha_0, \alpha_1, \dots)\\
y &= \operatorname{bode}(x; \alpha_0, \alpha_1, \dots)\\
\end{align}
The list of possibilities is essentially endless.

If the data is exact values derived from some complicated computations, then
a high order polynomial or rational polynomial fit would be my first choice.

If the data is experimental data with errors attached, then linear would be my first choice, then quadratic. If neither of work well, I would plot the data as
$\ln x$ vs $y$ or as $x$ vs $\ln y$ to see if I could transform the data into something that looked linear.

Warning. Fitting a nth degree polynomial to $n+1$ equally-spaced data points is a notoriously bad idea.

Comment: What is "bode" ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust. Its used in electrical engineering a lot. frequency responses of devices made from passive components (capacitors, inductors, resistors) have a very approximatable structure.

Comment: Thanks. Technically speaking, how does it work ? (The response of linear systems is a rational function in the Fourier domain, how is it approximated ?)

Comment: @YvesDaoust just do a google on bode plots.

Comment: Thanks, I know what a bode plot is. Is the method based on fitting a piecewise linear function on the amplitude curve in the bilogarithmic domain ? Or what ?

Comment: @yves yes. I realize now that I haven't really helped you any. I just wanted to point out why I feel that your question is not enough information. and my reason was too long for a comment.

Comment: Thanks Sir, I saw that "Warning. Fitting a nth degree polynomial to n+1 equally-spaced data points is a notoriously bad idea." It closer to my answer then How to get a way to make approximation equation?

Comment: @gmotree :  There is no easy answer to that question. Without any idea of the relationship between the points, there is no reliable way to come up with a model that fits the points. The polynomial will fit the points but it would be instructive for you to plot the polynomial and the points together.